# How to store user activity that supports undo?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I can track user activity on posts, so that users can see for example "2 updates!". The essence of the strategy I’m using leverages 2 tables:

---

**post_activity:**
`post_id | user_id | time_created`

**post_users:**
`post_id | user_id | time_created | time_last_seen`

---

With these 2 tables, I can query all records from `post_activity` where the `post_user.time_last_seen` is less than the `post_activity.time_created` for a count of all new items.

The problem is that `post_activity` is essentially an anonymous log, with no associated rows or notion of the type of action that caused it. What I can’t solve is for example this scenario:

- User A creates new post (1 new activity stored)
- User B comments on new post (1 new activity stored)
- User C sees "2 new!" but...
- User A *or* B deletes their contribution.

As far as the system is concerned, there are 2 unseen items but the user may see nothing!

*Can anyone provide a simple demonstration of how I might have a stronger relationship between activity and user actions here? Particularly one that supports unseen deleted activity?*

Comment: copy on write to post_activity_history table

Comment: Is Your story in chronological order?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `TRIGGER` on the table in which deletes are recorded and update related tables as required.

**Relevant postgresql documentation**

- Info about triggers: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/triggers.html
- How to create a trigger: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: I think triggers could be a good fit here, but what I’m still unclear on is how to target the right record in the activity table—I can’t just remove the most recent, because other activity may be generated before someone deletes an unseen post.